# Are all observed NGXS selectors executed on any state change?

Tags: angular, ngxs

All observed selectors executes even if I don't change part of the state participating in these selectors.

I have state containing 3 properties: "a", "b", "c", one action for updating property "a", 3 static selectors for all properties. My component subscribes to "b" using async pipe and to "c" using subscribe method from observable. When i dispatch new action changing "a", then "b" and "c" selectors get executed.

Here is an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-simple-1fte4j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I expect none of the selectors get executed. Maybe I'm wrong and this is expected behavior, but it means that I can't put any expensive logic into the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour in **earlier** versions of NGXS (like the one used in your StackBlitz `3.1.4`) - selectors were always passed the containing state as the first parameter causing them to be re-evaluated on any state change.

Latest version as of now (3.5) provides [Selector Options](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#selector-options) to change this - so check out that documentation.

Also see related [PR and linked issues](https://github.com/ngxs/store/pull/1029) around selector options.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about selector options, but didn't understand that if ngxs injects state as first parameter then selector depends on the entire state, but not on its properties used in this selector. Now I understand that that's the way memoized selectors work. Unfortunately I don't see it's explained in ngxs documentation, but in ngrx documentation. So I guess common approach would be to have 'elementary' selectors for properties and 'query' selectors with injected elemetray selectors in it for complex logic. In this case 'distinctUntilChanged' is somehow applied for the injected part.

Comment: None of this works. I have set this option to false and all my subscribes do not update on every state change, only when the change has a different payload

Comment: any solution for this? applying the select options doesn't have any effect

Comment: weird, but options set to false, false doesn't change anything in 3.7. 
Still when something in the state changed, all @selector like return state.a also triggered.
my options: selectorOptions: { suppressErrors: false, injectContainerState: false },

Comment: As far as I remember it never worked. Just place your selectors into a separate file and separate class and inject directly only what you need.

Comment: @AleksandrSkobeltcyn : it does work with (injectContainerState: false). see https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-simple-mq18ze?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts  BUT you have to build first level extractors of slice of your state that will ALWAYS be invoked. Then on subsequent selectors you can memoize costly computations. In the following example I add 3 extractor selectors called atomic_a atomic_b .. and on them I build the a,b,c selectors. Now you can see that atomics are always called. but subsequent a or b or c are never : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-simple-mq18ze?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: So this does not work with @SelectorOptions as recommended out of the box?